# Android can't reach URL using Volley library

Tags: android, mysql, xampp, httprequest, android-volley

Hi I write my app and have many problems but this is really strange.
All connections to mysql by php was working good. Today I everything was ok but suddenly i couldn't reach URL.

Here is the logcat:

```
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie I/System.out: AsyncTask #8 calls detatch()
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.20 refused
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:248)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:172)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:130)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1337)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:705)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:579)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:503)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:481)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at com.example.dawid.logowanie.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
05-18 19:06:00.310 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at com.example.dawid.logowanie.AddBookActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AddBookActivity.java:197)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at com.example.dawid.logowanie.AddBookActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AddBookActivity.java:156)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-18 19:06:00.320 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.20 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-18 19:06:00.330 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
05-18 19:06:00.330 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
05-18 19:06:00.330 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:    ... 16 more
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
05-18 19:06:00.340 21093-21353/com.example.dawid.logowanie W/System.err:    ... 21 more
```

In other cases pDialog shows I wait and wait and get nothing only:

```
05-18 19:10:05.850 27036-27036/com.example.dawid.logowanie E/RegisterActivity: Blad Rejestracji: null
05-18 19:10:05.900 27036-27036/com.example.dawid.logowanie D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
05-18 19:10:05.920 27036-27036/com.example.dawid.logowanie D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 7625 ms: [ ] http://192.168.1.20/android_login_api/Check.php 0x676929da NORMAL 1
05-18 19:10:05.920 27036-27036/com.example.dawid.logowanie D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{4c07063 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102039d android:id/toast_layout_root}
05-18 19:10:05.930 27036-27036/com.example.dawid.logowanie E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Like I said earlier everything was working fine but suddenly stopped. I restarted my phone many times, I change phone and nothing. I did Invalidate Caches/Restart but still have the problem.

Comment: Check the same request from postman or poster and see if ip is accessible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was because of  my home wifi network. I turned on hotspot on another phone and connect my laptop and phone to test and worked. I still don't understand how earlier everything was working on my home wifi and suddenly stopped.

Someone know how is it possible?